# Apply Post Class to Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, post-class

I am trying to add specific CSS post classes to the `services` custom post type. However, when I apply this function to the post class filter, it applies the function to all post types. My goal is to change the layout `services` archive page with CSS classes.

Is the problem with the `if ( is_singular('services') )` portion or does it have to do with the `global $wp_query;` which might be querying every post? Any solution would be greatly appreciated.

The full code:

```
add_filter( 'post_class', 'woo_custom_add_post_classes', 10);

function woo_custom_add_post_classes ( $classes ) {
    if ( is_singular('services') ) { return $classes; }


    global $wp_query; 

    // Get the number of the current post in the loop.
    $current_count = $wp_query->current_post + 1;

    // Work out whether this post is the last in a row.

    $iflast = 'last';

    if ($current_count % 3 == 0 ) { $iflast = 'last'; } else { $iflast = '';}

    // Add the classes to the array of CSS classes.
    $classes[] = 'service-number-' . $current_count; // Service number. 
    $classes[] = 'threecol-one';
    $classes[] = $iflast; // Last in the row or nothing 

    return $classes;

} // End woo_custom_add_post_classes()
```

Comment: Is this a typo? `if ( is_singular('services') ) { return $classes; }` ...I think you mean `if ( ! is_singular('services') ) { return $classes; }`?

Comment: I guess I should have read more thoroughly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conditionally check for post type like this:

**Code:**

```
if ( 'services' == get_post_type( $post->ID ) ) {
    //your code
}
```

See at the Codex: [Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_Post_Type), but `is_singular()` does this too.

Comment: I thought I tried this but apparently not. It worked...thanks!

Comment: Strange, because after I read Chip Bennett's comment, I was convinced he's right. Good thing I didn't deleted the answer. @IanRogers